# list of dicts - change key values from one to many to many to one

Tags: python

with a list of dict, say `list1` like below

```
[
  {'subId': 0, 'mainIds': [0]}, 
  {'subId': 3, 'mainIds': [0, 3, 4, 5], 'parameter': 'off', 'Info': 'true'}
]
```

Need to convert to below format.

```
[
  {'mainId': 0, 'subIds':[0,3]},
  {'mainId': 3, 'subIds': [3] },
  {'mainId': 4, 'subIds': [3] },
  {'mainId': 5, 'subIds': [3]}
]
```

What is tried so far

```
    finalRes = []
    for i in list1:
        subId = i['subId']
        for j in i['mainIds']:
            res = {}
            res[mainId] = j
            res['subIds'] = []
            res['subIds'].append(subId)
            finalRes.append(res)
```

This gives something closer to the required output. Need help with getting the output mentioned above. Is there any popular name for this kind of operation (something like one to many to many to one ?)

```
[
    {'mainId': 0, 'subIds':[0]},
    {'mainId': 0, 'subIds':[3]}
    {'mainId': 3, 'subIds': [3]},
    {'mainId': 4, 'subIds': [3]},
    {'mainId': 5, 'subIds': [3]}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kinds of joins can be implemented easily with `defaultdict`:

```
subs_by_main_id = defaultdict(list)
for entry in list1:
    sub_id = entry['subId']
    for main_id in entry['mainIds']:
        subs_by_main_id[main_id].append(sub_id)
return [{'mainId': main_id, 'subIds': sub_ids}
        for main_id, sub_ids in sub_by_main_id.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using comprehensions and [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable). Start by converting the lists to sets, for fast membership tests; then build the result directly. It is not as efficient as the `defaultdict` solution.

```py
from itertools import chain

sets = { d['subId']: set(d['mainIds']) for d in data }

result = [
    {'mainId': i, 'subIds': [ j for j, v in sets.items() if i in v ]}
    for i in set(chain.from_iterable(sets.values()))
]
```